# can't execute executable files in remote session of Powershell

Tags: powershell, remote-debugging

I have some scripts on a NAS and I'm trying to launch some installers stored on that NAS on a remote PC. I have my PC where I launch a remote PSsession in VS Code and with administrative credentials I'm able to execute and debug my script on the remote PC. Looking at the logs I noticed that my script does't launch any executable files when launched in remote. If I launch the script locally on that PC, it works well.
I suppose it'a matter of permissions or policy but nothing helped me.
Even this link [https://ss64.com/ps/enable-wsmancredssp.html](https://stackoverflow.com) found on a similar question didn'thelp.

**Every help will be appretiated!**

this is what I do:

```
Enter-Pssession -computername <remotepc> -credentials <admincredentials>
```

insert the password then I'm in.

```
set-executionpolicy -executionpolicy bypass -scope process
```

then I tryed to launch directly

```
& '.\Firefox Installer.exe'
```

and

```
start-process '.\Firefox Installer.exe'
```

but nothing happens on remote pc. If I launch start-process, my terminal on VS Code get stuck.

Comment: what happens if you use invoke-command instead?

Comment: @Bee_Riii I get an error `Impossibile risolvere il set di parametri utilizzando i parametri denominati specificati.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand` I tought Invoke-command is to use in a local session to send a command to remote, not in a remote session to send a command in the session itself, isn't it?

Comment: Besugo, @Bee_Riii: Yes, `Invoke-Command` is primarily useful to provide remoting _itself_, in combination with the `-ComputerName` parameter. (It _can_ be used locally, but there's no good reason to do so; if you use it locally, you must pass it a script block (`{ ... }` - which you can invoke more easily with `&`).

Answer (score 1):

**Launching *GUI* applications in a PowerShell remoting session isn't supported**, because the server component that services the caller's request runs in an invisible window station and the remoting protocol is solely based on communicating the output from *PowerShell commands* (including output from *non-interactive* console programs) back to the caller.

You have two options:

- In the case of an installer - if supported - pass it the appropriate command-line options to run *silently*, i.e. *without displaying a GUI and without requiring user interaction*.
- Use a Remote Desktop session instead, where you're free to launch GUI applications.

Comment: Finding a 'silent operation' switch is probably going to be the best long-term answer if you are using, or planning to use, automation.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to try and create a batch (.bat) that opens the powershell this is how I normally surpass some.
Like

BatchtoOpenprogram.bat

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File "C:\path\filename.ps1"
```

Then just run the .bat instead of remote powershell

Comment: This may work with some executables, but not the firefox installer since it is an interactive app as the question lists the usage.  See @mklement0's answer for why.